# Why is *dōna* the plural acc. Instead of *donos* like the rest of the 2nd declensions?

Tags: declension, morphology, accusative, neuter, second-declension

I am currently studying the declensions for nouns (currently on the 2nd one) and saw this difference.

*amīcōs, fīliōs, agrōs*

VS

*dōna*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Dōnum* is neuter; *amīcus, fīlius,* and *ager* are masculine. Neuter nouns are always the same in both the nominative and accusative case, in both singular and plural. See [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/18/accusative-equals-nominative-for-neuter-words-how-universal-is-this-and-why) for more about how universal this is.

Here are some more neuter nouns that you may be familiar with (from early chapters in *Lingua Latina Per Se Illustrata*):

> **Baculum** dominī in mēnsā est. *(Nominative)*
> Iūlius **baculum suum** sūmit et discēdit. *(Accusative)*

> In vīllā sunt duo **ōstia**: **ōstium magnum** et **ōstium parvum.**  *(Nominative)*
> Vīlla duo **ōstia** et multās fenestrās habet. *(Accusative)*

Neuter pronouns are also the same in nominative and accusative:

> **Illud** ōrnāmentum nōn tam pulchrum est quam **hoc**. *(Nominative)*
> Dā mihi **illud** mālum! *(Accusative)*
> Iūlius nihil ad **hoc** respondet. *(Accusative)*
> **Haec** verba ā Lȳdiā nōn audiuntur. *(Nominative)*
> Lȳdia **haec** verba nōn audit. *(Accusative)*

> **Quod** ōrnāmentum est ānulus? *(Nominative)*
> Ānulus est ōrnāmentum **quod** digitum ōrnat. *(Nominative)*
> Ōrnamentum **quod** Lȳdia in collō habet est līnea margaritārum. *(Accusative)*
> **Quae** ōrnāmenta ab Albīnō venduntur? *(Nominative)*
> Ōrnamenta **quae** Albīnus vendit sunt ānulī. *(Accusative)*

Answer (score 8):

This is because of the gender of the noun. *Donum* is neuter, wheras *filius*, *amicus*, etc, are masculine. The plural accusative for [2nd declension neuter nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_declension#Second_declension_(o_stems)) is *-a*.

Answer (score 7):

*donum* is neuter, and hence its ending in both the nominative and accusative plural is *-a*.