# Should these "vellus" be "vellerum"?

Tags: grammar-identification, noun, accusative, nominativus

I read the following text in the book [*Método de Latín I*](https://books.google.it/books?id=lXrR3dtHDhgC&pg=PA52&lpg=PA52&dq=%22cum+rapere+voluisset+vellus%22&source=bl&ots=BZrMhT0nqN&sig=ACfU3U1RjhG9aHTO5AfGNMSd7RfeHdvpUw&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwixqa3XhOSCAxUUcaQEHdXEAxMQ6AF6BAgHEAE#v=onepage&q=%22cum%20rapere%20voluisset%20vellus%22&f=false) by Santiago Segura Munguía, published by the University of Deusto (emphasis mine on the words that cause me difficulty):

> Multas fabulas a Graecis accepimus. Nobilis est fabula quae
> miram Iasonis Argonautarumque navigationem narrat. Iason,
> filius Thessaliae regis, cum rapere voluisset **vellus** aureum arietis,
> qui olim duos fratres per aera (*por los aires*) transportaverat,
> magnam expeditionem paravit (*organizó*). Rex Colchorum **vellus** aureum servabat, custoditumque erat ab immani dracone
> taurisque feris, qui flammas ore vomebant. Cum Iason immensam navem, quae Argo dicta est, construxisset, et in navem
> conscendisset cum Theseo, et Hercule multisque Graeciae principibus in Colchidem pervenit. Ibi a a Medea, regis filia, adiutus
> est. Cum Iason Colchidae regem post (*después de*) multos labores devicisset, **vellus** aureum rapuit et Medeam in patriam
> secum devexit. Cum Argonautae in Graeciam venissent, Olympicos ludos instituerunt, qui ab omnibus Graeciae populis semper celebrati sunt.

It seems to me that these three *vellus* should be *vellerum*: *vellus* is nominative singular, so it should be the subject or a predicative complement of the subject of the sentences, but I believe that this doesn't make sense. If *vellerum* was used instead of *vellus*, it would be the direct object of the sentences, something that makes complete sense. So, is this an error in the book? Or am I missing something?

The curious thing is that this book has been [translated to Catalan](https://books.google.it/books?id=gZfC1BYmKwMC&pg=PA49&lpg=PA49&dq=%22cum+rapere+voluisset+vellus%22&source=bl&ots=59iTFjDq13&sig=ACfU3U3ovK60rA61fYxcPf3L5-wtxQ6nmg&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwixqa3XhOSCAxUUcaQEHdXEAxMQ6AF6BAgFEAE#v=onepage&q=%22cum%20rapere%20voluisset%20vellus%22&f=false) and published by the University of Barcelona, but you can find the same text with these three *vellus* in the translation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Vellus* is a neuter noun, and [neuter nouns have the same form in both the nominative and accusative cases](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/18/accusative-equals-nominative-for-neuter-words-how-universal-is-this-and-why).

The proper accusative singular of *vellus* is *vellus*. *Vellerum*, meanwhile, is the genitive plural, as [this paradigm chart](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/3rd-declension-mute-stems-n) will show you.

Comment: Note that if it were not neuter, it would be *vellerem* (e.g. *Romani Venerem colebant*).

Comment: Follow up question to that comment: Are there third declension masculine or feminine nouns (_not_ neuter) with nom. sing. ending in _-us_?

Comment: @NicolasMiari Sebastian lists one: *Venus*.

Comment: Shouldn’t Colchidae in the second to last sentence be Colcihdis?

Comment: @Patricius It does seem to be an error. Google Books doesn't allow me to access the link, so I don't know if it's Munguía's error or what.